# How to convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Record> to List<Record>

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

How does one retrieve the list in a model?

This is what I'm trying:

```
private void cbxPlayers_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
            string selectedPlayer = cbxPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString();
            using (ProgressRecordContext context = new ProgressRecordContext())
            {
                records = (from Player in context.Players
                          where Player.Name == selectedPlayer
                          select Player.Records).ToList<Record>();
            }
        }
```

That doesn't work however, what am I missing?

These are the models in case they're needed:

```
public class Player
    {
        [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int AccountNumberId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }

public class Record
    {
        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        public int AccountNumberId { get; set; }

        public double Level { get; set; }
        public int Economy { get; set; }
        public int Fleet { get; set; }
        public int Technology { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT: Here's the error messages:

Error   1   'System.Linq.IQueryable>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList(System.Linq.ParallelQuery)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

EDIT:

I see that I probably wasn't very clear with what I was trying to do. I eventually worked out a way to do what I wanted and here it is:

```
private void cbxPlayers_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lstvRecords.Items.Clear();
            if(cbxPlayers.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }
            string selectedPlayer = cbxPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString();
            using (ProgressRecordContext context = new ProgressRecordContext())
            {
                var records = from Player in context.Players
                          from Record in context.Records
                          where Player.Name == selectedPlayer &&
                          Player.AccountNumberId == Record.AccountNumberId
                          select new
                          {
                              Level = Record.Level,
                              Economy = Record.Economy,
                              Fleet = Record.Fleet,
                              Technology = Record.Technology,
                              Experience = Record.Experience,
                              TimeStamp = Record.TimeStamp
                          };

                foreach (var element in records)
                {
                    string[] elements = {element.Level.ToString(),
                                            element.Economy.ToString(),
                                            element.Fleet.ToString(),
                                            element.Technology.ToString(),
                                            element.Experience.ToString(),
                                            element.TimeStamp.ToString()
                                        };
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(elements);
                    lstvRecords.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to write that query or is the way that I've done it correct?

Comment: Your code looks ok, in what way is it not working?

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an empty list back?

Comment: See my edit for the error messages

Answer (score 6):

No idea why you're getting `ParallelQuery` - unless you've got some wacky `using`s in your source file.

In any case, you appear to have an enumerable of enumerables - try `SelectMany` (note you need `using System.Linq;` for this to work as an extension method, too):

```
records = (from Player in context.Players 
           where Player.Name == selectedPlayer 
           select Player.Records).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
```

Also - unless you intend to add/remove to/from that list, you should just use an array, i.e. use `.ToArray()`.

As pointed out by @Tim S (+1) - if you expect only a single player here then you should be using `SingleOrDefault()` to get the single player - whose `Records` you then turn into an array/list.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `Player.Records` is a `List<Record>`, and you are getting an `IEnumerable<List<Record>>` (i.e. 0 to many player's records) from your query, so `.ToList()` gets you a `List<List<Record>>`.  If there are multiple players with the same name and you want it to collect the records from all of them, use Andras Zoltan's solution.  If you want to ensure (via throwing an exception if there are 0 or more than 1 results) that exactly one player has the given name, and only his records are returned, use one of these solutions: (key change being [`.Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) - also take a look at [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494540.aspx) to see if it fits your needs better)

```
//I prefer this solution for its conciseness and clarity.
records = context.Players.Single(Player => Player.Name == selectedPlayer).Records;

//if you'd like to use the LINQ query format, I'd recommend this.
records = (from Player in context.Players
          where Player.Name == selectedPlayer
          select Player).Single().Records;

//this is more similar to your original query.
records = (from Player in context.Players
          where Player.Name == selectedPlayer
          select Player.Records).Single().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
     List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
```

to

```
     var records = new List<List<Record>>();
```

Does it work? If a Player has a list of Records, it looks like your query is returning a List of a List of Records.

Edit:
There, fixed the return list... either way this is probably not the solution you're looking for, just highlighting what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try refactoring your query

```
records = context.Players.First(player => player.Name == selectedPlayer).Records.ToList();
```